# Geometric interpretation of a Linear problem with bounded variables

Tags: linear-programming, optimization

I have a question of how to make a geometric interpretation of this problem

\begin{eqnarray}
 \mbox{max} &  z = 3x_1+x_3 \\ 
 s.a: & \\
 & \begin{array}{cc}
      x_1+2x_2+x_3+x_4& =10 \\
      x_1-2x_2+2x_3&=6\\
      1 \leq x_1\leq 4&\\
      -5 \leq x_2 \leq 4\\
      0 \leq x_3 \leq 4&\\
      0 \leq x_4 \leq 5&
 \end{array} 
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: How about solve for $x_3$ and $x_4$ explicitly (through the equality constraints), then plot the resulting inequalities as a polytope and the objective function as the level sets

Comment: The question is clear, but I have some questions about the title. What does PL stand for? Is this a misspelling of LP? Also, I am not familiar with the term "channeled variables".

Comment: "Programação linear com varíaveis canalizadas" in portuguese translates to "Linear programming with bounded with bounded variables"

Comment: Sry, typo, only "Linear programming with bounded variables".

Comment: Perhaps this is clear to others, but it is not clear to me what a "geometric interpretation" of an LP is. Can you clarify or provide a reference if this is an often used term?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

From the first two constraints you will cancel out $x_2$ which gives you: $2x_1 + 2x_3 + x_4 = 16$. Now, you can solve for $x_4$ and substitute that in the last constraint ($0 \le x_4 \le 5$) and you will have a system which only relies on $x_1$ and $x_3$